# Using webkit to render html pages

Tags: javascript, java, webkit, headless

I want to render the HTML of a website and execute any synchronous and asynchronous javascript and then access the resulting DOM tree. And this has to be done headlessly.

I am currently trying to bypass the javafx WebEngine and trying to work directly on the webkit wrapper.

I can get the HTML to load just fine, but I can not seem to get it to:

- load additional resources (javascript, css,...)
- execute the javascript

I have set up a very simple test html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script
                  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
                  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
                  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("load", function () {
                console.log("loaded!");
                document.body.innerHTML = "haha!!";
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>hello!</body>
</html>
```

The java code looks like this (the web page is `com.sun.webkit.WebPage`):

```
WebPage page = new WebPage(
        new WebPageClientImpl(),
        new UIClientImpl(), 
        new PolicyClientImpl(),
        new InspectorClientImpl(), 
        new ThemeClientImpl(),
        false);

page.addLoadListenerClient(new LoadListenerClientImpl());
page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
page.open(page.getMainFrame(), url);
```

And not entirely sure yet what it does but I send out a tick every second:

```
Timer.getTimer().notifyTick();
```

When I access the resulting DOM tree, I see the HTML but the javascript has not been executed.

Does anyone know how to get the page to render fully?

Alternative suggestions to rendering html+javascript headlessly are also welcome. Note that there does not need to be any visualization, I simply need programmatic access to the DOM tree.